# Is there a way to collect the following through REST on XtremIO

Tags: rest, storage

Is there a way to collect the following through REST on XtremIO?

- SNMP
- SYSLOG

I can't find that here:

```
https://support.emc.com/docu56460_XtremIO-3.0.1,-3.0.2,-3.0.3-and-3.0.5-Storage-Array-RESTful-API-Guide.pdf?language=en_US
```

Is there a newer REST version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a updated version with all the data I needed:
https://www.dellemc.com/pt-pt/collaterals/unauth/quick-reference-guides/products/storage/docu88753.pdf